# TinyMCE onmouseover event, open menu item without click

Tags: javascript, tinymce

When you click a menu item first time, the others automatically open onmouseover event. But if you don't click, the others do not open onmouseover event. But I want to open a menu item while onmouseover event without any click. How can I do this?
[image]

Comment: I understand now, noone uses TinyMCE.

Comment: TinyMCE isn't using an iframe. So you can easily use `mouseover` event. Use developer console to inspect the element. You can see that they have assigned an `id` to each button, ex. `File` is `mce_25-open`, `Edit` is `mce_26-open`, etc

Comment: Now, I noticed. Anymore, I will try all conbinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.mce-menubtn', function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('mce-active'))
        $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

Maybe not good solution, but context menu generate by click.
You can check here: http://coding.kz/stack/tinymce.html

*for answer in comments*

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.mce-menubtn', function() {
    menuItem = $(this);
    if (!menuItem.hasClass('mce-active'))
        menuItem.trigger('click');
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.mce-menu', function() {
        if (!$('.mce-menu-sub-tr-tl:visible').length) $('.mce-menu').hide();
        menuItem.removeClass('mce-active');
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.mce-menu-sub-tr-tl', function() {
        if (!$('.mce-menu-sub-br-bl:visible').length) $('.mce-menu').hide();
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.mce-menu-sub-br-bl', function() {
        $('.mce-menu').hide();
});
```

Comment: The important thing is solving the problem. By suggesting a better idea, ​​whether this is the best.

Comment: Ok, Well, how do we mouseleave event? `$("body").on('mouseenter','.mce-menubtn', function() { if(!$(this).hasClass('mce-active')) $(this).trigger('click'); }).on("mouseleave", ".mce-menubtn", function() { **???** });`

Comment: I'm sorry I asked missing question. mouseleave event, opened menu must close again. But in the updated answer, it is not. Sorry again for my short English knowledge.

Comment: i updated answer, also you can see it at my page http://coding.kz/stack/tinymce.html , but menu not closed if event mousover not happened. Sorry but i don't know another solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the Init Script you can set up your own Event handlers.

Use something like this, and then check for the menu, I have not in mind,
how the elements are called but ID, names and classes can be found in sourcecode.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // Custom Commands
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.on("keyup change mouseup", function(e) {}
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately nothing did not change.